# Pass MySQL table record to variable based on session ID

Tags: php, mysql, session, session-variables

I Have the following PHP code (which works) for pulling the clients email address from our MySQL DB based on their $_SESSION clientid variable and storing it on $myemail:

```
mysql_select_db($dn) or die(mysql_error());

$clientid = ($_SESSION['clientid']);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT emailaddress FROM clients WHERE clientid = '" . $clientid . "'");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

$myemail = $row[0];

}

mysql_close($con);
```

But was wondering whether or not there was a better way of doing this?

Comment: Your code is perfect. Just stop using `mysql_*` because its deprecated, Start using `mysqli` OR `PDO`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all don't use mysql_* functions as they are deprecated. Better to use PDO or mysqli.
And regarding your question i would write

```
$clientId = $_SESSION['clientid'];

$res = mysql_fetch_object(mysql_query("SELECT emailaddress FROM clients WHERE clientid = '{$clientId}'"));

$email = $res->emailaddress;
```

One more thing why do you need while loop? While loop is not at all necessary as we are fetching a single record.

Comment: Thanks for this. Worked great. Will also read up on mysqli. Thought I could just replace all 'mysql_' functions with 'mysqli'.

Answer (score 2):

It seems your code is vulnerable from sql injection. use `prepare statement` or use `mysql_real_escape_string`. here is the code...

```
mysql_select_db($dn) or die(mysql_error());

$clientid = ($_SESSION['clientid']);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT emailaddress FROM clients WHERE clientid = '" . $clientid . "'");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $myemail = mysql_real_escape_string($row['emailaddress']);
}

mysql_close($con);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Replace**

```
$myemail = $row[0];
```

**With**

```
$myemail = $row['emailaddress'];
```

Comment: first one is fine because OP is fetching array not assoc.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Why is this? P.S. Array formats are a little confusing to me at the moment.